# partial calling the same controller independently of the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sorry by the dummy question, but I'm just starting with rails.

I have a partial that should be used in my whole site as a sidebar. It shows a category list that I've initialized in the "homeController".

when I'm in the home page it works fine. The problem appears when I go to another page (like userController) because there's no category list.

One possible solution is initialize this list in every controller, but it does not seems "DRY" to me.

Is there any solution that I can use without repeat myself everytime?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a [before_action](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action) in your `ApplicationController`, it will be inherited by all controllers that inherit from `ApplicationController`.

Usually, most or all of your regular controllers ought to inherit from `ApplicationController`.

```
# inside ApplicationController...
before_action :set_categories

def set_categories
  @categories = Category.all
end
```